# What is the reason I have to use spread operator in React hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

**Expected behavior**

To rendered counter increase by one on each click

**Actual behavior**

Rendered counter doesn't increase, but internal does (as seen by alert messages). And look at this screenshot: http://prntscr.com/ujtsu9 (it doesn't happen all the time..)

**Code**

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App(props) {
  const [all, setAll] = useState([{ name: "PHP", votes: 1 }]);

  function changeAll() {
    const newAll = all;
    alert(newAll === all); //alert true

    newAll[0].votes++;
    setAll(newAll);

    alert(all[0].votes);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="voteCount">{all[0].votes}</div>
      <div className="lanugageName">{all[0].name}</div>
      <button onClick={changeAll}>Click Here</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**What I have tried:**

changing the line `const newAll = all;` -> to -> `const newAll = [...all];`
Then it works. But, then alert says 'false'

**Question**

- Why do I need to use spread operator?
- Why is `newAll === all` false if I use spread operator?

Comment: You need to make a copy of `all` because you cannot mutate the state directly. Using the spread operator is one way of making a copy. Arrays are objects, so `===` will compare their identities and not their values.

Comment: @iz_ is it because arrays are assigned by reference not by value? so if i do newAll = all then they are actually the same? I just remembered this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do I need to use spread operator?

You don't *need* to use the spread ***syntax*** *, but you *do* need to shallowly copy existing state you intend to mutate into new object/array/memory references. Using the spread syntax is one of the ways to achieve this. When working with array is it also common to use many of the array functions that return *new* array, i.e. map, filter, slice.

> Why is `newAll === all` false if I use spread operator [***syntax*** *]?

When you `const newAll = all` you are saving the reference to the state `all` to `newAll` as well, but you `const newAll = [...all]` you are first spreading the state into a *new* array reference *then* saving it to `newAll`

Try it out

```js
const all = [1,2,3];

const newAll1 = all;
const newAll2 = [...all];

console.log(newAll1 === all); // true
console.log(newAll2 === all); // false
```

* [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

I want to also caution you against patterns like this

```
newAll[0].votes++;
setAll(newAll);
```

Even though you shallowly copied `all`, `newAll[0].votes++` would still be considered a state mutation. If you need to update an element of an array in react state then you should *also* shallowly copy the properties of any object you intend to update.

```
setAll(all.map((el, index) => !index ? el : { ...el, votes: el.votes + 1 }))
```

More importantly, if any state update *depends* on existing state (incrementing a count is the default example, BTW) you would want to use a functional update.

```
setAll(all => all.map((el, index) => !index ? el : { ...el, votes: el.votes + 1 }))
```